# How does one obtain the area of a general polygon set in CGAL?

Tags: c++, cgal

In the following CGAL example, drawn from [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/index.html), I have a union of circles and rectangles. It looks like so:

[image: Circles and rectangles union]

How do I get the area of the resulting union using CGAL?

```cpp
// Compile with: clang++ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DCGAL_USE_GMPXX=1 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -march=native -frounding-math bob.cpp -lgmpxx -lmpfr -lgmp

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Gps_circle_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/General_polygon_set_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h>
#include <list>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                   Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Circle_2                                  Circle_2;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel>         Traits_2;
typedef CGAL::General_polygon_set_2<Traits_2>             Polygon_set_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_2                       Polygon_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_with_holes_2            Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                                 Curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                      X_monotone_curve_2;
// Construct a polygon from a circle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (const Circle_2& circle)
{
  // Subdivide the circle into two x-monotone arcs.
  Traits_2 traits;
  Curve_2 curve (circle);
  std::list<CGAL::Object>  objects;
  traits.make_x_monotone_2_object() (curve, std::back_inserter(objects));
  CGAL_assertion (objects.size() == 2);
  // Construct the polygon.
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 arc;
  std::list<CGAL::Object>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter) {
    CGAL::assign (arc, *iter);
    pgn.push_back (arc);
  }
  return pgn;
}
// Construct a polygon from a rectangle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (const Point_2& p1, const Point_2& p2,
                             const Point_2& p3, const Point_2& p4)
{
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 s1(p1, p2);    pgn.push_back(s1);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s2(p2, p3);    pgn.push_back(s2);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s3(p3, p4);    pgn.push_back(s3);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s4(p4, p1);    pgn.push_back(s4);
  return pgn;
}
// The main program:
int main ()
{
  // Insert four non-intersecting circles.
  Polygon_set_2 S;
  Polygon_2 circ1, circ2, circ3, circ4;
  circ1 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(1, 1), 1));  S.insert(circ1);
  circ2 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(5, 1), 1));  S.insert(circ2);
  circ3 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(5, 5), 1));  S.insert(circ3);
  circ4 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(1, 5), 1));  S.insert(circ4);
  // Compute the union with four rectangles incrementally.
  Polygon_2 rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4;
  rect1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(1, 0), Point_2(5, 0),
                            Point_2(5, 2), Point_2(1, 2));
  S.join (rect1);
  rect2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(1, 4), Point_2(5, 4),
                            Point_2(5, 6), Point_2(1, 6));
  S.join (rect2);
  rect3 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 1), Point_2(2, 1),
                            Point_2(2, 5), Point_2(0, 5));
  S.join (rect3);
  rect4 = construct_polygon(Point_2(4, 1), Point_2(6, 1),
                            Point_2(6, 5), Point_2(4, 5));
  S.join (rect4);
  // Print the output.
  std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2> res;
  S.polygons_with_holes (std::back_inserter (res));
  std::copy (res.begin(), res.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<Polygon_with_holes_2>(std::cout, "\n"));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the area of the whole greater square (no round borders) minus the area of the white square minus 4x ( the area of the smallest square - 1/4 area of black circle ).

Comment: @Niloct: Obviously so, but the question is how you determine this using CGAL; the example configuration is only an example.

Comment: @Richard - have you seen my answer? Do I need to make further improvements/clarifications in it?

Comment: @HEKTO: My apologies, I was working on another project. Your answer is great - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General polygons with possibly circular edges don't have the `area` function - so we need to get into details of their representation and write this kind of functions ourselves (sigh!!). An example of such an `area` function is below:

```
// ------ return signed area under the linear segment (P1, P2)
auto area(Traits_2::Point_2 const& P1, Traits_2::Point_2 const& P2)
{
  auto const dx = CGAL::to_double(P1.x()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.x());
  auto const sy = CGAL::to_double(P1.y()) + CGAL::to_double(P2.y());
  return dx * sy / 2;
}

// ------ return signed area under the circular segment (P1, P2, C)
auto area(Traits_2::Point_2 const& P1, Traits_2::Point_2 const& P2, Circle const& C)
{
  auto const dx = CGAL::to_double(P1.x()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.x());
  auto const dy = CGAL::to_double(P1.y()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.y());
  auto const squaredChord = dx * dx + dy * dy;
  auto const chord = std::sqrt(squaredChord);
  auto const squaredRadius = CGAL::to_double(C.squared_radius());
  auto const areaSector = squaredRadius * std::asin(std::min(1.0, chord / (std::sqrt(squaredRadius) * 2)));
  auto const areaTriangle = chord * std::sqrt(std::max(0.0, squaredRadius * 4 - squaredChord)) / 4;
  auto const areaCircularSegment = areaSector - areaTriangle;
  return area(P1, P2) + C.orientation() * areaCircularSegment;
}

// ------ return signed area under the X-monotone curve
auto area(X_monotone_curve_2 const& XCV)
{
  if (XCV.is_linear())
  {
    return area(XCV.source(), XCV.target());
  }
  else if (XCV.is_circular())
  {
    return area(XCV.source(), XCV.target(), XCV.supporting_circle());
  }
  else
  {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

// ------ return area of the simple polygon
auto area(Polygon_2 const& P)
{
  auto res = 0.0;
  for (auto it = P.curves_begin(); it != P.curves_end(); ++it) res += area(*it);
  return res;
}

// ------ return area of the polygon with (optional) holes
auto area(Polygon_with_holes_2 const& P)
{
  auto res = area(P.outer_boundary());
  for (auto it = P.holes_begin(); it != P.holes_end(); ++it) res += area(*it);
  return res;
}
```

As you can see I used here `Polygon_with_holes_2` access functions `outer_boundary`, `holes_begin` and `holes_end`. For `Polygon_2` I used only `curves_begin` and `curves_end` access functions. Much more efforts are required to process edges of this polygon, which are of the `X_monotone_curve_2` type. All these access functions will be necessary for any other functions you'll need to develop for general polygons.

A full MWE incorporating your example is below:

```cpp
// Compile with: clang++ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DCGAL_USE_GMPXX=1 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -march=native -frounding-math bob.cpp -lgmpxx -lmpfr -lgmp

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Gps_circle_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/General_polygon_set_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h>

#include <list>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                   Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Circle_2                                  Circle_2;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel>         Traits_2;
typedef CGAL::General_polygon_set_2<Traits_2>             Polygon_set_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_2                       Polygon_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_with_holes_2            Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                                 Curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                      X_monotone_curve_2;

//For two circles of radii R and r and centered at (0,0) and (d,0) intersecting
//in a region shaped like an asymmetric lens.
constexpr double lens_area(const double r, const double R, const double d){
  return r*r*std::acos((d*d+r*r-R*R)/2/d/r) + R*R*std::acos((d*d+R*R-r*r)/2/d/R) - 0.5*std::sqrt((-d+r+R)*(d+r-R)*(d-r+R)*(d+r+R));
}

// ------ return signed area under the linear segment (P1, P2)
auto area(const Traits_2::Point_2& P1, const Traits_2::Point_2& P2){
  auto const dx = CGAL::to_double(P1.x()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.x());
  auto const sy = CGAL::to_double(P1.y()) + CGAL::to_double(P2.y());
  return dx * sy / 2;
}

// ------ return signed area under the circular segment (P1, P2, C)
auto area(const Traits_2::Point_2& P1, const Traits_2::Point_2& P2, const Circle_2& C){
  auto const dx = CGAL::to_double(P1.x()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.x());
  auto const dy = CGAL::to_double(P1.y()) - CGAL::to_double(P2.y());
  auto const squaredChord = dx * dx + dy * dy;
  auto const chord = std::sqrt(squaredChord);
  auto const squaredRadius = CGAL::to_double(C.squared_radius());
  auto const areaSector = squaredRadius * std::asin(std::min(1.0, chord / (std::sqrt(squaredRadius) * 2)));
  auto const areaTriangle = chord * std::sqrt(std::max(0.0, squaredRadius * 4 - squaredChord)) / 4;
  auto const areaCircularSegment = areaSector - areaTriangle;
  return area(P1, P2) + C.orientation() * areaCircularSegment;
}

// ------ return signed area under the X-monotone curve
auto area(const X_monotone_curve_2& XCV){
  if (XCV.is_linear())
  {
    return area(XCV.source(), XCV.target());
  }
  else if (XCV.is_circular())
  {
    return area(XCV.source(), XCV.target(), XCV.supporting_circle());
  }
  else
  {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

// ------ return area of the simple polygon
auto area(const Polygon_2 P){
  auto res = 0.0;
  for (auto it = P.curves_begin(); it != P.curves_end(); ++it) {
    res += area(*it);
  }
  return res;
}

// ------ return area of the polygon with (optional) holes
auto area(const Polygon_with_holes_2& P){
  auto res = area(P.outer_boundary());
  for (auto it = P.holes_begin(); it != P.holes_end(); ++it) {
    res += area(*it);
  }
  return res;
}

// Construct a polygon from a circle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (const Circle_2& circle){
  // Subdivide the circle into two x-monotone arcs.
  Traits_2 traits;
  Curve_2 curve (circle);
  std::list<CGAL::Object>  objects;
  traits.make_x_monotone_2_object() (curve, std::back_inserter(objects));
  CGAL_assertion (objects.size() == 2);
  // Construct the polygon.
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 arc;
  std::list<CGAL::Object>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter) {
    CGAL::assign (arc, *iter);
    pgn.push_back (arc);
  }
  return pgn;
}

// Construct a polygon from a rectangle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (
  const Point_2& p1,
  const Point_2& p2,
  const Point_2& p3,
  const Point_2& p4
){
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 s1(p1, p2);    pgn.push_back(s1);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s2(p2, p3);    pgn.push_back(s2);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s3(p3, p4);    pgn.push_back(s3);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s4(p4, p1);    pgn.push_back(s4);
  return pgn;
}

double area(const Polygon_set_2& Pset){
  std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2> res;
  Pset.polygons_with_holes(std::back_inserter(res));
  double ret = 0;
  for(const auto &x : res){
    const auto temp = area(x);
    if(!std::isnan(temp)){ //TODO: This seems to be necessary, but I'm not sure why
      ret += area(x);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

void test1(){
    // Insert four non-intersecting circles.
  Polygon_set_2 S;

  const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(1, 1), 1));
  const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(5, 1), 1));
  const auto circ3 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(5, 5), 1));
  const auto circ4 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(1, 5), 1));
  S.insert(circ1);
  S.insert(circ2);
  S.insert(circ3);
  S.insert(circ4);

  // Compute the union with four rectangles incrementally.
  const auto rect1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(1, 0), Point_2(5, 0),
                                       Point_2(5, 2), Point_2(1, 2));
  const auto rect2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(1, 4), Point_2(5, 4),
                                       Point_2(5, 6), Point_2(1, 6));
  const auto rect3 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 1), Point_2(2, 1),
                                       Point_2(2, 5), Point_2(0, 5));
  const auto rect4 = construct_polygon(Point_2(4, 1), Point_2(6, 1),
                                       Point_2(6, 5), Point_2(4, 5));
  S.join(rect1);
  S.join(rect2);
  S.join(rect3);
  S.join(rect4);

  // Print the output.
  std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2> res;
  S.polygons_with_holes (std::back_inserter (res));
  std::copy (res.begin(), res.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<Polygon_with_holes_2>(std::cout, "\n"));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for(const auto &x: res){
    std::cout << "Area = "<< area(x)<< " and should be "<<(4*8-4+M_PI)<<std::endl;
  }
}

void test2(){
  Polygon_set_2 S;
  const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(0, 0), 1));
  const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(0.5, 0), 1));
  S.join(circ1);
  S.join(circ2);
  std::cout<<"Number of holes was "<<(S.number_of_polygons_with_holes()==1)<<" should be 1"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Area was "<<CGAL::to_double(area(S))<<" should be "<<(2*M_PI - lens_area(1, 1, 0.5))<<std::endl;
}

void test3(){
  Polygon_set_2 S;
  const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(0, 0), 1));
  const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(0.5, 0), 1));
  const auto circ3 = construct_polygon(Circle_2(Point_2(-1.8, 0), 1));
  S.join(circ1);
  S.join(circ2);
  S.join(circ3);
  std::cout<<"Number of holes was "<<(S.number_of_polygons_with_holes()==1)<<" should be 1"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Area was "<<CGAL::to_double(area(S))<<" should be "<<(3*M_PI - lens_area(1, 1, 0.5) - lens_area(1, 1, 1.8))<<std::endl;
}

// The main program:
int main (){
  std::cout<<"test1"<<std::endl;
  test1();
  std::cout<<"test2"<<std::endl;
  test2();
  std::cout<<"test3"<<std::endl;
  test3();

  return 0;
}
```

Running the `test1` gives an output of `31.1416`. You have four rectangles of area 8 each with four overlapping regions of area 1 and 4 quarter circles giving: `4*8-4+π=31.141592653589793`, so the results match the theory. Other two tests also work OK.

Comment: @Richard - thank you for adding testing results, I'm glad they were correct.

Comment: I think this is incorrect for the case where there are two circles each of radius 1 with the first centered at (0,0) and the second centered at (0.5,0). In that case the area should be (area of circles) - (area of lens) = 2π - 2.152 = 4.13108, but your code is returning 4.09047. I wonder if there's a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Thanks! I've put a file with an MWE of the test case mentioned above here: https://gist.github.com/r-barnes/84463af92fd561b7aebc4c88f4078af3 (@hekto)

Comment: @Richard - I've fixed my code and updated my answer, including your test program with three tests. By the way, your `test3` was incorrect a little bit - there should be `3*M_PI` in the stream output operator. I'm sorry it took that long.

Comment: Thanks, @HEKTO. A question: why do we need to use `to_double` so often? It seems like that might lead to a loss of precision?

Comment: @Richard - because arrangements with circular edges need the `Sqrt_extension` type for point coordinates, and values of this type can't be added or subtracted in general case

Comment: @Richard - however, converting these values to doubles isn't the only way - please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789481/converting-coordinate-values-in-cgal#60798865