# Computing the area of a general polygon in CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to use the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399922/how-does-one-obtain-the-area-of-a-general-polygon-set-in-cgal) to compute area of a general polygon in CGAL:

```
auto squared_distance(const Traits_2::Point_2& P1, const Traits_2::Point_2& P2)
{
  const auto dx = P1.x() - P2.x();
  const auto dy = P1.y() - P2.y();
  return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}

auto area(const Polygon_2& P)
{
  auto res = 0.0;
  for (auto it = P.curves_begin(); it != P.curves_end(); ++it)
  {
    if (it->is_linear())
    {
      const auto s = it->source();
      const auto t = it->target();
      res += CGAL::to_double((s.x() - t.x()) * (s.y() + t.y()) / 2);
    }
    else if (it->is_circular())
    {
      const auto s = it->source();
      const auto t = it->target();
      res += CGAL::to_double((s.x() - t.x()) * (s.y() + t.y()) / 2);
      const auto ds = CGAL::to_double(squared_distance(s, t));
      const auto rs = CGAL::to_double(it->supporting_circle().squared_radius());
      const auto areaSector = rs * std::asin(std::sqrt(ds) / (std::sqrt(rs) * 2));
      const auto areaTriangle = std::sqrt(ds) * std::sqrt(rs * 4 - ds) / 4;
      res += (areaSector - areaTriangle);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

auto area(const Polygon_with_holes_2& P)
{
  auto res = area(P.outer_boundary());
  for (auto it = P.holes_begin(); it != P.holes_end(); ++it) res += area(*it);
  return res;
}
```

However, the code seems to be incorrect. A minimum (non-)working example is adapted from the linked question above:

```
// Compile with: clang++ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DCGAL_USE_GMPXX=1 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -march=native -frounding-math bob.cpp -lgmpxx -lmpfr -lgmp

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Gps_circle_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/General_polygon_set_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Lazy_exact_nt.h>

#include <list>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                   Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Circle_2                                  Circle_2;
typedef CGAL::Gps_circle_segment_traits_2<Kernel>         Traits_2;
typedef CGAL::General_polygon_set_2<Traits_2>             Polygon_set_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_2                       Polygon_2;
typedef Traits_2::General_polygon_with_holes_2            Polygon_with_holes_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                                 Curve_2;
typedef Traits_2::X_monotone_curve_2                      X_monotone_curve_2;

auto squared_distance(const Traits_2::Point_2& P1, const Traits_2::Point_2& P2){
  const auto dx = P1.x() - P2.x();
  const auto dy = P1.y() - P2.y();
  return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}

auto area(const Polygon_2& P){
  double res = 0.0;
  for (auto it = P.curves_begin(); it != P.curves_end(); ++it){
    if (it->is_linear()){
      const auto s = it->source();
      const auto t = it->target();
      res += CGAL::to_double((s.x() - t.x()) * (s.y() + t.y()) / 2);
    } else if (it->is_circular()) {
      const auto s = it->source();
      const auto t = it->target();
      res += CGAL::to_double((s.x() - t.x()) * (s.y() + t.y()) / 2);
      const auto ds = CGAL::to_double(squared_distance(s, t));
      const auto rs = CGAL::to_double(it->supporting_circle().squared_radius());
      const auto areaSector = rs * std::asin(std::sqrt(ds) / (std::sqrt(rs) * 2));
      const auto areaTriangle = std::sqrt(ds) * std::sqrt(rs * 4 - ds) / 4;
      res += (areaSector - areaTriangle);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

auto area(const Polygon_with_holes_2& P){
  auto res = area(P.outer_boundary());
  for (auto it = P.holes_begin(); it != P.holes_end(); ++it) {
    res += area(*it);
  }
  return res;
}

// Construct a polygon from a circle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (const Circle_2& circle){
  // Subdivide the circle into two x-monotone arcs.
  Traits_2 traits;
  Curve_2 curve (circle);
  std::list<CGAL::Object>  objects;
  traits.make_x_monotone_2_object() (curve, std::back_inserter(objects));
  CGAL_assertion (objects.size() == 2);
  // Construct the polygon.
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 arc;
  std::list<CGAL::Object>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = objects.begin(); iter != objects.end(); ++iter) {
    CGAL::assign (arc, *iter);
    pgn.push_back (arc);
  }
  return pgn;
}

// Construct a polygon from a rectangle.
Polygon_2 construct_polygon (
  const Point_2& p1,
  const Point_2& p2,
  const Point_2& p3,
  const Point_2& p4
){
  Polygon_2 pgn;
  X_monotone_curve_2 s1(p1, p2);    pgn.push_back(s1);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s2(p2, p3);    pgn.push_back(s2);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s3(p3, p4);    pgn.push_back(s3);
  X_monotone_curve_2 s4(p4, p1);    pgn.push_back(s4);
  return pgn;
}

// The main program:
int main (){
  Polygon_set_2 S;
  const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 0), 0.5);
  const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(5, 0), 0.5);

  // Comment and uncomment these blocks to switch between examples

  // const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 0), 2);
  // const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(5, 0), 2);

  // const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 0), 2);
  // const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(2, 0), 2);

  // const auto circ1 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0, 0), 1);
  // const auto circ2 = construct_polygon(Point_2(0.5, 0), 1);

  S.join(circ1);
  S.join(circ2);

  // Print the output.
  std::list<Polygon_with_holes_2> res;
  S.polygons_with_holes (std::back_inserter (res));
  std::copy (res.begin(), res.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<Polygon_with_holes_2>(std::cout, "\n"));
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for(const auto &x: res){
    std::cout << "Area = "<< area(x) <<std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the tests I have run:

1. Two non-overlapping circles of radius 0.5 centered at (0,0) and (5,0). The area given by the code is π, but the correct answer should be 0.5π. This is the MWE above.
2. Two non-overlapping circles of radius 2 centered at (0,0) and (5,0). The code returns 0.
3. Two overlapping circles of radius 2 centered at (0,0) and (2,0). The code returns 0.
4. Two overlapping circles of radius 1 centered at (0, 0) and (0.5, 0). As noted in the linked question, the true answer is 4.13108 but the code returns 4.09047.

Comment: I've fixed code in my answer (the first line), please take a look. Any questions - please let me know.